# How to get expect_equal() function (package testthat) work with rmarkdown files?

Tags: r, r-markdown, testthat

I would like to use function `expect_equal()` from the package `testthat` in a `rmarkdown` file, but the execution of rendering (started with the `Knit` button in `RStudio`) is halted and no output is produced.

A minimal example is given in the file `error.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "error"
author: "N"
date: "4 października 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(testthat)
```

```{r ex1, error=TRUE}
a <- (1:5)
a[p]
```

```{r ex2, error=TRUE}
expect_equal(10, 10)
expect_equal(10, 10 + 1e-7)
expect_equal(10, 11)
```
````

In the second chunk `ex2`, the line `expect_equal(10, 11)` should produce an error, but the rendering of the file should not be stopped due to the chunk option `error=TRUE`. However, the rendering is stopped and no output is produced.

The output from rendering is as follows:

```
processing file: error.Rmd
  |.........                                                    |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                          |  29%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |............................                                 |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                        |  57%
label: ex1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ error: logi TRUE

  |..............................................               |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................................     |  86%
label: ex2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ error: logi TRUE


BŁĄD: 10 not equal to 11.
1/1 mismatches
[1] 10 - 11 == -1
Wykonywanie wstrzymane
```

The polish term "BŁĄD" means "ERROR" and "Wykonywanie wstrzymane" means "Execution halted".

The chunk `ex1` works as expected: the expression `a[p]` results in an error, the error message is placed in the output and the rendering is continued.

In the chunk `ex2` the first two expression do not produce errors and, with the third expression commented out, the output is correctly rendered.

Other functions from the package `testthat` used instead of the third expression, e.g. `all.equal(10,11)` works well and do not stop the rendering.

Using another function from `testthat`, `expect_identical()`, also stops the rendering process.

Search with different combinations of the keywords `r`, `rmarkdown`, `testthat`, `expect_equal`, `"stop on error"` does not result in valid solution to the problem.

Could you reproduce this unexpected behavior?

Any suggestions, how to use the function `expect_equal` in `rmarkdown` and get the final output (if this behavior is not the result of error in the function `expect_equal` itself)?

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] testthat_1.0.2       rmarkdown_1.0.9016   RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      crayon_1.3.2     digest_0.6.10    assertthat_0.1   R6_2.1.3         formatR_1.4      magrittr_1.5    
 [8] evaluate_0.9     stringi_1.1.2    RevoUtils_10.0.1 tools_3.3.1      stringr_1.1.0    rsconnect_0.4.3  yaml_2.1.13     
[15] htmltools_0.3.5  knitr_1.14       tibble_1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just wrap `test_that()` around your `expect_equal()` expressions:

````
---
title: "error"
author: "N"
date: "4 października 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(testthat)
```

```{r ex1, error=TRUE}
a <- (1:5)
a[p]
```

```{r ex2, error=TRUE}
test_that(desc = 1, expect_equal(10, 10))
test_that(desc = 2, expect_equal(10, 10 + 1e-7))
test_that(desc = 3, expect_equal(10, 11))
```
````

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you. The code in chunk `ex2` is taken directly from [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) book by Hadley Wickham, chapter "Testing". Why there it is supposed to work without the sourounding function `test_that()` ?

Comment: Hadley does indeed use `expect_equal()` without wrapping `test_that()` around it. When I copy the raw Rmd of his chapter on testing and try knitting it I run into the same problem that failing expectations interrupt the knitting process. Not sure why it seems to work for him :/